# Error while using write_xes function : Error in defaultvalues[[datatype]] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r

I want to export an eventlog object built in R using bupaR package function - eventlog as an xes file. For that I am using function `write_xes()` of package xesreadR. But the function is giving out error :
Error in defaultvalues[[datatype]] : invalid subscript type 'list'

```
>class(log)

output:

[1] "eventlog"   "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"


write_xes(log,"myxes.xes")
```

According to the documentation it should save the log to the destined file.But instead it is producing the error :

> ERROR : Error in defaultvalues[[datatype]] : invalid subscript type
>   'list'

I have tried multiple things to troubleshoot this problem but haven't came up with a solution. So can somebody help me to solve this error. Thank You!

Comment: `write_xes(log, file="myxes.xes")` see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/edeaR/versions/0.5.0/topics/write_xes

Answer (score 0):

Your function is defined as follow:

```r
write_xes ( eventlog, case_attributes = NULL, file = file.choose())
```

Thus, writing
`write_xes(log,"myxes.xes")`
 means
`write_xes(eventlog = log, case_attributes = "myxes.xes")`.

Instead, you shall write

```r
write_xes(eventlog = log, file = "myxes.xes")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the real problem was that one of the attributes of the eventlog data was not correctly defined. So after correctly that the error was solved.